# Site incorrectly shows that I have modified questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

I noticed that the [PA website](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com) seems to be incorrectly reporting that somebody has modified a question. The system said I modified a question before I even made any edits. I think what probably happened is that I voted to close or reopen that question.

Has anyone else had similar issues? Or is this the correct behavior (what's considered a modification)?

Just wanted to raise the issue here in case it is a system bug. I think the post in question was:

[Proof assistants for beginners - a comparison](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/43)

If I recall, it showed that I "modified date at time" on the home page.

Now it only shows "xxx asked date at time", which does not reflect the fact that the post was modified later on. In any case, the status on a post does not seem to reflect the last action correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior since you was the last one who voted to reopen the post ([The fifth voter](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/posts/43/timeline#history_12565914-42cd-4f15-abab-9bf0875ff727)).

A question will be marked with "modified by" and bump to the top of the homepage if anyone of the following actions was taken on it:

- Edits to the questions. (Obviously)
- Someone edits an answer on the question. (Even if the answer is deleted.)
- The last voter to reopen a question (The fifth voter).
- The question is bumped by the community user.